# How to add ajax to a button that deletes table rows?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a project in which a delete button deletes the row from table. But the list page gets reloaded everytime I delete an entry. I dont want it to reload. I just want it to remove the entry from list page but I am not good with ajax. Please help me with the code. Thanks in advance.

centrelist.html

```
 <script>
 $(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
 var a ;
 a=confirm("Do you really want to delete the user?");
 if(a==true){
  var url = "{% url 'NewApp:centredelete' pk=1%}"
  var id = $(this).attr('name')

  document.location.href = url.replace('1',id);
 }
});
</script>

 <tbody>
    {% for c in centres %}
       <tr>
         <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.address }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.contact  }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.phone }}</td>
         <td><a href="{% url 'NewApp:centreupdate' slug=c.slug %} " style="color:black; margin-left:8px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></i></a><a href="#" style="color:black ;margin_left:8px;" id="delete" name="{{c.id}}" ><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></i></a></td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

views.py

```
def CentreDeleteView(request, pk):
  centre = Centre.objects.get(pk=pk)
  centre.delete()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('NewApp:centrelist'))
```

Comment: I just did not post the decorators.I am sorry but others are not as idiot as you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.get()` to open an URL in the background without reloading.

After the URL has been loaded, the element is deleted from the database and you can delete the row in HTML table

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('click','#delete',function()
    {
        var a ;
        a=confirm("Do you really want to delete the user?");
        if(a==true)
        {
             var url = "{% url 'NewApp:centredelete' pk=1%}"
             var id = $(this).attr('name')
             url = url.replace('1', id);
             // Open url in background
             $.get(url, function(data)
             {
                 // Delete element from table
                 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
             });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the url needs to be more dynamic. You dont want to delete the object with the pk of 1 all the time! And use post instead of GET

Comment: I am not. I am replacing 1 with the id later.

Comment: I have not actually worked with this kind of function. Can you please help me with what to write inside the get url function.

Comment: @Srvastav4 You have to delete the element from the page because it's deleted and it no longer exists. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to avoid the refresh page behavior you need to do two things:

- When click on a delete anchor you should prevent the browser to follow the link.
- When the request is received you should delete the html node containing the target `tr`

Try with something similar to this code. Probably the code needs some changes to handle error situations and add the confirm dialog if you want.

```html
<tbody>
    {% for c in centres %}
       <tr data-row-item-id="{{ c.pk }}">
         <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.address }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.contact  }}</td>
         <td>{{ c.phone }}</td>
         <td>
            <a href="{% url 'NewApp:centreupdate' slug=c.slug %} " style="color:black; margin-left:8px">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </i></a>

           <a data-action="delete" 
              data-item-id="{{ c.pk }}"
              data-endpoint="{% url 'NewApp:centredelete' c.pk %}"
               href="#" 
               style="color:black ;margin_left:8px;" 
               id="delete" 
               name="{{c.id}}" >
                <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    function addDeleteEventListener(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            const endpoint = btn.dataset.endpoint
            $.post(endpoint)
                .done(() => {
                    const elementToDelete = document.querySelector(`[data-row-item-id=${btn.dataset.itemId}]`)
                    elementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elementToDelete)
                })
        })
    }


    const deleteButttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-action=delete]")
    deleteButtons.forEach(btn => {
        addDeleteEventListener(btn)
    })
})
```